# Split string into sentence list by dot & linebreaks

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp

I have a string and I want to split it into sentences. To do so I'm using "NLTK" and "sent_tokenize"

`h2text_list = nltk.tokenize.sent_tokenize(h2listtotal[xx][1])`

However, the issue is that it doesn't recognize linebreaks ("/n") as new sentences, instead, it only recognizes a new sentence if it ends in a dot (.)

I need it to recognize the linebreaks as well (while still keeping them). Basically split a text into sentences and add each sentence to a list based on dots and linebreaks (while still keeping them in the text inside the list).

If it also recognizes ! and : and ? as possible linebreaks too that's even better!

Examples of text that keeps triggering the errors:

```
Here are sample some food sources of vitamin K: 10 sprigs of parsley contains 90 micrograms (mcg)

a 3-ounce serving of natto contains 850 mcg

a half-cup serving of frozen and boiled collard greens contains 530 mcg

one cup of raw spinach contains 145 mcg

1 tablespoon of soybean oil contains 25 mcg

a half-cup serving of grapes contains 11 mcg

a hard-boiled egg contains 4 mcg Most adults in the U.S. are believed to consume enough vitamin K. Recipe tips These healthy recipes have been developed by a registered dietitian.
```

This is all considered a SINGLE sentence by "nltk.sent_tokenize" because it only ends in "." at the very end.

Comment: Please post your text in question, and also a [minimum reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to work with

Comment: @AnandGautam The text is constantly changed because I'm scraping news articles but I'll post an example.

Comment: Not a [mre]. You could change it to first splittin your scraped text by \n - then you nltk every list entry. Then you cry over `'At 37.3 °C a patient should be ok.`

Comment: Maybe replacing `'\n'` with `'.'` would help you out.

Comment: @PatrickArtner I tried: 
h2text_list = nltk.tokenize.sent_tokenize(h2listtotal[xx][1].replace("\n","»."))
    for phrase in h2text_list:
     if "»." in phrase:
      phrase = phrase.replace("».","\n")

However it's still happening and for some reason, NLTK is still not splitting it properly